# How to combine count, case when, and In

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table called matter

| mclient | mstatus |
| --- | --- |
| 075551 | CL |
| 075551 | CL |
| 075551 | CL |
| 075551 | OP |

I had hoped the query

```
select 
m.mclient
, count (mstatus) [Total Matters]
, count (case when m.mstatus in ('OP', 'OI', 'OC', 'OT') then 1 else 0 end) as [ActiveMatters]
from matter m
where m.mclient = '075551'
group by m.mclient
order by m.mclient desc
```

Would Deliver

| mclient | Total Matters | ActiveMatters |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 075551 | 4 | 1 |

But instead it is delivering

| mclient | Total Matters | ActiveMatters |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 075551 | 4 | 4 |

Comment: Replace the 2nd `count()` with `sum()`. This is how *conditional aggregation* is done.

Comment: COUNT is fine, but you need to replace 0 with NULL to skip it from counting (ELSE NULL is default so it can be removed entirely): `, count (case when m.mstatus in ('OP', 'OI', 'OC', 'OT') then 1 end) as [ActiveMatters]`

Comment: `count(expr)` counts all non-null values, including 0.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this, you should use SUM with your CASE statement, so that it adds up the number of times the condition is true

```
SELECT
    m.mclient,
    COUNT(m.mstatus) AS [Total Matters],
    SUM(CASE WHEN m.mstatus IN ('OP', 'OI', 'OC', 'OT') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Active Matters]
FROM matter m
WHERE m.mclient = '075551'
GROUP BY m.mclient
ORDER BY m.mclient DESC
```

Comment: To see what is counted (or summed) you can use [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), see: https://dbfiddle.uk/pxQ60ucK    (and `0` is counted.... )

Comment: That's a `case` _expression_.

Answer (score 0):

There is a more elegant way of doing what you want using the [`FILTER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) clause available in PostgreSQL (fiddle available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/emUiG9Hf)).

```
SELECT
  mclient,
  COUNT(mstatus),
  COUNT(mstatus) FILTER (WHERE mstatus IN ('OP'))
FROM
  test
-- WHERE mclient = xyz
GROUP BY mclient;
```

Result:

```
mclient  Total  Op count
  75551      4         1
```

Also works for:

```
SELECT
  mclient,
  COUNT(mstatus) AS "Total",
  COUNT(mstatus) FILTER (WHERE mstatus IN ('OP', 'OI', 'OC', 'OT')) AS "Op count"
FROM
  test
-- WHERE mclient = 012345
GROUP BY mclient;
```

Answer (score 0):

FOR SQL SERVER

Data Insert :

```
Create table #matter (mclient int, mstatus varchar(10) )
Insert into #matter Values(075551,'CL'),(075551,'CL'),(075551,'CL'),(075551,'OP')
```

Your same query can be used also but with a slight tweak:

```
select 
m.mclient
, count (mstatus) [Total Matters]
, count (IIF(m.mstatus in ('OP', 'OI', 'OC', 'OT'),1,NULL) ) as [ActiveMatters]
from #matter m
where m.mclient = '075551'
group by m.mclient
order by m.mclient desc
```

You can also use your query but you need this.

```
select 
m.mclient
, count (mstatus) [Total Matters]
, count (case when m.mstatus in ('OP', 'OI', 'OC', 'OT') then 1 else NULL end) as [ActiveMatters]
from #matter m
where m.mclient = '075551'
group by m.mclient
order by m.mclient desc
```

You can see I replaced the else statement 0 with NULL.
So what happens is that count ignores Null.